# Maven, remove part of version and replace with build number

Tags: maven, bamboo

In my pom.xml the version is 1.0-SNAPSHOT. I'm using bamboo to deploy the snapshot to nexus using:

```
mvn clean deploy
```

The problem is that I want the project version to appear in nexus as 1.0-22 (The build number, 22 is just an example) and not 1.0-SNAPSHOT.

I know in bamboo I can use:

```
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=1.0-${build.buildNumber}
mvn clean deploy
mvn versions:revert
```

The problem is I don't want to hard code 1.0 into all my bamboo builds because that part might change in the future and if it does I don't want to go into bamboo to change it. Also, I need the version to stay as 1.0-SNAPSHOT in the pom.xml because it's deploying to other places and not just nexus. Is there a way to change part of a version number using a command? i.e removing the -SNAPSHOT part and replacing it with the build number and then reverting back to the old snapshot version when deploying elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

If you're running on a Unix based system you could try:

```
BASE_VERSION=$(mvn org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-help-plugin:2.1.1:evaluate -Dexpression=project.version | grep SNAPSHOT | grep -v INFO | sed 's/-SNAPSHOT//g')
mvn versions:set -DnewVersion=$BASE_VERSION-${build.buildNumber}
mvn clean deploy
mvn versions:revert
```

You may need to adjust the `BASE_VERSION` string as I'm not 100% sure how it may function on a multi-pom project.